# the logic of pushing up and sorting a data list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 100 rows of textarea(s) that a user may add information to (not in any particular order) the textareas look like this:

```
var item='<textarea class="itemv"id="k'+k+'"rows="1"style="width:100%;border:none;border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;outline:none;resize:none;background:none;font-weight:bold;">'+_.k+'</textarea><br>';
```

I am attempting to 'push up' all values that aren't 'undefined' into any blank textareas. leaving blank text areas at the bottom and populated textareas at the top. I am in doing this preserving the order in witch things were written by the user, here is the code:

```
$('#save2').unbind().bind('click', function () {
  $($('#items .itemv').get().reverse()).each(function () {
    var $prev = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace('k', '')) - 1;
    $prev = $('#k' + $prev);
    if ($(this).val() !== '' && $prev.val() === '') {
      $prev.val($(this).val());
      $(this).val('');
      //do again
      $($('#items .itemv').get().reverse()).each(function () {
        var $prev = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace('k', '')) - 1;
        $prev = $('#k' + $prev);
        if ($(this).val() !== '' && $prev.val() === '') {
          $prev.val($(this).val());
          $(this).val('');
          //do again
          $($('#items .itemv').get().reverse()).each(function () {
            var $prev = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace('k', '')) - 1;
            $prev = $('#k' + $prev);
            if ($(this).val() !== '' && $prev.val() === '') {
              $prev.val($(this).val());
              $(this).val('');
              //do again
              $($('#items .itemv').get().reverse()).each(function () {
                var $prev = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace('k', '')) - 1;
                $prev = $('#k' + $prev);
                if ($(this).val() !== '' && $prev.val() === '') {
                  $prev.val($(this).val());
                  $(this).val('');
                }
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

my problem is that I am running this code multiple times to get the job done (rather silly really) I can't get my head around the logic. If I only run it once like:

```
$($('#items .itemv').get().reverse()).each(function () {
  var $prev = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace('k', '')) - 1;
  $prev = $('#k' + $prev);
  if ($(this).val() !== '' && $prev.val() === '') {
    $prev.val($(this).val());
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

then only the first textareas value that is after a textarea with a value of undefined gets pushed up to the top, its new value becomes the second text area that would be moved to the top. I would like to solve this with out the use of a sorting plugin, can someone help me understand the logic?

fixed... with the help of @Patrick Evans in chat

```
$($('#items .itemv').get().reverse()).each(function(){ 
    var $prev=parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace('k','')) - 1;$prev=$('#k'+$prev); 
    if( $(this).val() != "" &&$prev.val()==='') { 
        $('#items .itemv').filter(function(){return this.value=="";}).first().val(   $(this).val() );$(this).val(''); 
} 
});
```

Comment: Holy moly that code scares me

Answer (score 1):

goes through each textarea and if it isnt empty puts its value into the first textarea that doesnt have a value.

```
$('#items .itemv').each(function(){
    if( $(this).val() != "" ) {
        $('#items .itemv').filter(function() {
            return this.value=="";
        }).
        first().
        val( $(this).val() );
        $(this).val("");
    }    
});
```

Comment: but my textareas are all named the same as my sql database columns k1,k2,k3 etc...

Comment: that doesnt matter, it doesnt change their names or anything it just puts the textarea to the bottom of the list. or are you trying to fill the k1, k2, so on first?

Comment: I need the sql database to reflect the look of the list so data in k1,k2,k3 is populated where as further down the line k98,k99,100 might be blank, so by naming my textareas as my database columns and pushing up the values i can then save to the databsae in that order.

Comment: updated answer. this will go though them all and if there is a value find  the first textarea that doesnt have a value and put it in there.

Comment: no that just fills all 100 rows with duplicate values (just pasted/tried it)

Comment: it still populates all texareas

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32643/discussion-between-patrick-evans-and-ben-muircroft)

Comment: Perhaps a sort on the textareas ?  var ar=$('#items .itemv'); ar.sort(function(a, b) { ...} );

Comment: this was already solved he used a variant of this, as it wasnt fully working.